# Allowing `undefined` as a valid select menu option (in Angular)?

Tags: html, angular

I'm unsure if this is an Angular issue, or a general restriction of HTML forms.

I would like a [select form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) with three values: `true`, `false`, and, `undefined`. See [this Stackblitz](https://angular-rc3fjd.stackblitz.io) or code below.

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-select formControlName="test" value="undefined">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let v of values"
                [value]="v.value">{{ v.display }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

...and the corresponding `.ts` file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public readonly values: any[] = [
    {
      display: 'true',
      value: true
    },
    {
      display: 'false',
      value: false
    },
    {
      display: '--',
      value: undefined
    }
  ];

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      test: undefined
    });
  }
}
```

However, while hard-coding `test` to `true` or `false` works:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      test: true // 'true' or 'false' selected in form.
});
```

...`undefined` does not:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      test: undefined // '--' option is *not* selected.
});
```

Comment: What about using `'undefined'` (string as a value)?

Comment: The form is bound to a view which requires the value be `undefined` for certain behaviour.  Making `undefined` a string results in `"undefined"` being rendered in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting anything to `undefined` is considered a bad practice.

In this particular case, probably the best solution is to use empty string as a default value.

If you look into material's code you will see that null/undefined is treated as special reset value: [Material Source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts#L804)